# WLOG Can assume length of 1.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am looking at a proof of the following:

$$\mathbb{P}(\sum a_iX \ge t)\le \text{exp}\bigg(\frac{-t^2}{||a||_2}\bigg)$$

They start WLOG we can assume $||a||^2_2=1$. I am trying to understand why this is the case. The only thing I can come up with is that I can rescale

$$\mathbb{P}(\sum a_iX \ge t)=\mathbb{P}(\sum \frac{a_iX}{||a||_2} \ge \frac{t}{||a||_2})=\mathbb{P}(\sum \frac{a_iX}{||a||_2} \ge k)$$

for some $k\ge 0$

Is my logic correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your rescaling is wrong. You should rescale by $\|a\|_2$ (not $\|a\|_2^2$): note that otherwise it won't be homogeneous.

---

In more detail, note that if you prove the case for unit vectors, then indeed the general case follows:

$$\mathbb{P}\left\{\sum_i a_iX_i \ge t\right\}=\mathbb{P}\left\{\sum_i \frac{a_iX_i}{\|a\|_2} \ge \frac{t}{\|a\|_2}\right\}=\mathbb{P}(\sum_i a'_iX_i \ge t') \stackrel{(\ast)}{\leq} e^{-{t'}^2} = e^{-\left(\frac{t}{\|a\|_2}\right)^2} = e^{- \frac{t^2}{\|a\|_2^2}}$$
where for $(\ast)$ we applied the result to $a' = \frac{a}{\|a\|_2}$ (which is a unit norm vector by construction) and $t' = \frac{t}{\|a\|_2}$.

Comment: what do you mean by won't be homogeneous?

Comment: @NoeVidales I mean that if you rescale by $\|a\|_2^2$ instead of $\|a\|_2$, then you have issues: replace $a$ by $b=\lambda a$, then your new vector has norm $\frac{\lambda a}{\lambda^2\|a\|_2^2} = \frac{a}{\lambda\|a\|_2^2}$ (so it does not actually rescale well -- that thing won't be of unit norm for arbitrary $\lambda$). A reasonable rescaling should be scale-invariant -- the $\lambda$ should cancel.

Comment: In general, for those things, "think like a physicist." If $a$ has a unit (e.g., a vector meters), then after rescaling you should get a unit-free thing (so you can rescale by a length, but not by a squared length).